# WPF App with WCF Data - EF, Linq2Sql or WCF Data Services - None Seem 'Easy'

Tags: wpf, wcf, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, ado.net

I am doing something I consider to be pretty normal (although I personally haven't had to do it before), and I have assumed there'd be a 'no-brainer' way forward, but Im yet to find it - which is really frustrating.

I will be creating a WPF application, which is a data-oriented business application. My data will come from a remote IIS server (that I control) that has a standard SQL server 2008 database, so Web services/WCF seem to be the way forward. The remote service needs to be secure (reasonably) via a user (of the WPF client) username/password login.

I dont want to use 3rd party ORM products, but I expect the data layer (between the service and the database) to be able to cope with very simple ORM type functionality (I really dont want to hand-craft a data retrieval and persistence layer). Im not worried about concurrency very much as this will be a fairly simple app.

My options seem to be one of the following:

1. ADO.NET Entity Framework over WCF
2. Linq2Sql over WCF
3. WCF Data Services

On further investigation, none of the above seem to be the 'no brainer' Im after

1) ADO.NET entity Framework - Ive had a play with this and getting all sorts of issues serializing objects over WCF. Even when  I try to generate POCO entities and use them, Im having to decorate service contracts with custom attributes just to get it to not error all the time, and I seem to have to hand-crank anything more than a flat object graph. It seems to me that EF simply isn't designed to be exposed via a service.

2) Linq2Sql - This doesn't seem much better than EF. I seem to have to hand-crank too much stuff. Ive tried the designer and SQLMetal but nothing seems to 'just work' - it all needs fiddling with.

3) WCF Data Services - this seems like a good option on the face of it, but essentially it seems like I'm just exposing my SQL database tables 'in the raw' over the service layer. Im not an expert in this technology by any means but it seems like a potentially dangerous approach, and on top of that it doesnt seem to support any kind of access security as standard (you have to hack it to require authentication it seems).

As I said, this scenario feels like it should have a no-brainer solution, but Im still scratching my head. Ive done lots of things with .NET technologies, but to be honest this area represents a bit of a hole in my understanding, so I apologize if any of my comments or assumptions are naive.

Of course, it may well be that the 'hacky' long-way-round on EF or Linq2SQL may be all I can do, in which case I can roll up my sleeves, and accept the fact that I haven't missed a more elegant solution.

Any help/advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tad subjective, but i'll offer **my opinion.**

First of all, forget L2SQL - it's basically obsolete and doesn't have the full POCO support of EF4 (it can be done, but needs XML tinkering, or SQLMetal generation), which means serializaing your entities will be a left-to-right entity cloning nightmare.

I would go with ADO.NET Entity Framework over WCF, Entity Framework 4.0 specifically. You will have a wealth of flexibility in your model (including the ability to apply OO principles such as inheritance).

Use **Self-Tracking-Entities**. Yes, you have to decorate service contracts - this is by design, and there are many reasons for this.

You could always use DTO's, as opposed to serializing the actual EF entities.

OData is really good as well in it's flexibility and simplicity. But if your only consuming your model via a single client application, a specialized service layer (WCF) is a better approach IMO.

Comment: I agree that for any new application EF is the way to go, not L2S. L2S however does support POCO (and it did so from the very beginning). Just google 'LINQ to SQL POCO'.

Comment: @Steven - didn't know that. Then again i haven't touched L2S in a while - i'm a EF groupie. :)

Comment: Yes it seems that self-tracking-entites may be the way forward. Ive found a good run-down (see link) and will give them a try - thanks
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/22/feature-ctp-walkthrough-self-tracking-entities-for-the-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> 3) WCF Data Services - this seems like
>   a good option on the face of it, but
>   essentially it seems like I'm just
>   exposing my SQL database tables 'in
>   the raw' over the service layer.

That might be a first impression - but it's fundamentally wrong. What you're exposing over the web is a **model** - and you have full control over what gets into that model, and how consumers of your WCF Data Services might be able to see and/or even update entities in that model.

That's where Entity Framework comes in and shines (and where Linq-to-SQL miserably fails): you can grab your database (or at least parts of it) into an Entity Data Model, and then modify it. You can tweak your entity names to be totally different from your table names, you can add computed attributes, you can remove certain attributes and much more.

If you're talking about a fairly simple app, that's definitely the way I'd go:

- grab your database and turn it into an Entity Data Model using EF
- expose that EDM over WCF Data Services and define what can be seen read-only, and what might even be updated over the wire